# How to slowly print the output while having it processed in background and go to current execution position when key is pressed?

Tags: python, time, printing

I have a big file on which I apply functions on each lines and print the output line by line. But since the input file is huge, it takes time to process and I cannot let the user wait for the final input. I also cannot let the user see the output being print very fast. Even if I use the `sleep` function, it'll take too much time with a file of few millions of lines. Therefore, my question is: Is there a way to slowly print what has been processed, so that the user can see (and read) the output, considering that the program is still processing the big file, in such a way that when the user presses a key, it'll send him directly to the most recent part of program being processed (and then slowly print again)?
I aim for something similar to this:

```py
from random import *
from time import sleep

with open('bigfile.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()
    for i in range(len(lines)):
        print(lines[i] + ' ' + str(randint(0,9)))
        sleep(0.5)
        # if key_is_pressed:
        #    goto current execution position
        #    slowly print until key is pressed again
```

Comment: you can use threads or corutines for this

Comment: Do the processing in the background via a thread and have it put results into a shared `Queue` which the foreground thread can slowly display.

Comment: Or just: Read one line. Process one line. Print one line. Rinse and repeat. No need to read *all* lines right from the start. No need for threads!

Comment: @quamrana: That would not allow for background processing—although I agree the entire file does not need to be read into memory first.

Comment: Or use threads. Start a background thread which just: Reads one line. Processes one line. Sends result into queue. Foreground thread blocks on queue, then prints one line and sleeps. But if a key has been pressed (seach stackoverflow for this), clear the queue.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for your clear comments. Using threads makes sense in this case.

Comment: Also, to indicate end of input, one technique is for a `None` to be sent into the queue which the sender and receiver agree means its the end. (Threads can be joined and programs exited).